# How create multi column editing in scene view on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, layout, uicollectionview

I'm ios developing beginner. And I'm very interested in creating one App having features like those in app [Kanbana - your personal task manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kanbana/id581409040?mt=8), which one scene view can display multi column sections for editing. 
I'm curious about what ios technology can achieve that? Does it use UICollectionView, or draw each section on the scene?

Comment: You can use UICollectionView, and for each cell of UICollectionView you can create a Cell of different Items which will list in either UIScrollView or, UITableView.

Comment: Do you mean each column can be created by each cell of UI collectionview, and then in each cell I create UIScrollview as its contentview. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can use UITableView instead of UIScrollView too.. Its just like CustomCell for UICollectionView

Comment: Is it possible to do like this: I use each section of uicollectionview  as each column, and then create cells in each section/column as subview.  if that the issue is how do I set section/column horizontally extending

Comment: If you have problem using UICollectionView, it can easily be done using simple UIScrollView, create a CustomView with Vertical subitems, and add those in ScrollView horizontally.